# Nexus 7 System error 'show low battery logo'

Tags: battery, 4.1-jelly-bean, system-error, nexus-7

Today I finally got my Nexus 7 though the post and turned it on; I was just checking charge. I got an 'out of battery' UI message and the tablet then turned itself off.

I plugged in the USB charger to the wall and attached the Mini-usb to the tablet and waited an hour. Now, when I try hit the on switch the tablet seems to be running, but I'm confronted with a terminal type windows which says 'show low battery logo'. I did some Googling' and I only found on other thread which wasn't much use.

I am unable to go to another menu and it's a simple command line type message, hitting the screen and the home button is not visible.

Should I leave the tablet to de charge (take forever) or should I continue charging?

Answer (score 1):

By searching in Google, I landed in a discussion thread on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1798756).  It seems that this issue is a software bug and just to troubleshoot, keep the battery charged fully and see at what level of the battery this issue comes up. And you are being referred in that discussion as well ;-)

Comment: I managed to boot the Nexus, by charging via USB.